# How would I turn a spoken number into an integer in javascript?

Tags: javascript, frontend, numbers

In a script that I wrote for voice recognition, I stumbled upon a problem. I could not convert the given format of number into an integer, eg: "five", to a number, eg: "5"

Some examples of what I've tried to do is to convert seven to 7
or nine to 9, and twenty five to 25.

So far I've just been using if () statements, but it becomes obvious that this approach will not work in the long term, when converting numbers such as one hundred and twenty six to 126.
Here is my current code:

```
if (numberString == "one") {
   number = 1;
}
    if (numberString == "two") {
   number = 2;
}
    if (numberString == "three") {
   number = 3;
}
```

I've already tried all the standard solutions, like parseInt and Number, but all of them returned NaN(Not a Number).

Comment: Please take a moment to read [ask]. Include your current code, and please make sure to include plenty of example cases so it's obvious what you're asking for.

Comment: What would the input representation of `13` or `24032` be?

Comment: @code The input representation of 13 would be thirteen, and the input representation of 24032 would be twenty four thousand and thirty two. I've updated my post to include a code snippet and more examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In JavaScript, you can use a third-party library called **words-to-numbers** to achieve this.
- You can install the words-to-numbers library using npm by running the following command in your terminal.

  ```
   npm install words-to-numbers
  ```
- After the library is installed, you can use it in JavaScript code as below.

  ```
   const wordsToNumbers = require('words-to-numbers');
   let numberInWords = "five";
   number = wordsToNumbers(numberInWords);
  ```
- check this link for more information https://www.npmjs.com/package/words-to-numbers